# update row if date is more recent

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with 11000 rows (two columns are URN and date) and I want to add rows to it. 
However if the URN is already there when adding the new rows, it should overwrite the previous record so the date is updated.
for example,

```
select urn, GETDATE() AS Date
into table1
from table2
```

if urn 10253 has date 23/05/2005 in table1 but the urn is in table2 then it should be replaces with urn 10253 date 10/10/2012

Comment: You might be interested in [MERGE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) statement.

Comment: @MichalKlouda: **IF** he's using SQL Server **2008** or newer... `MERGE` isn't available in 2000 or 2005 ...

Comment: That's right, that's why he *might be* interested ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

--Update all the matching records first

```
Update t1 SET date=t2.date 
from table1 t1 inner join table2 t2 
on t1.urn=t2.urn
```

--Insert all the new records

```
INSERT INTO table1
select * from table2 t1 where NOT EXISTS(select * from table1 t1 where t1.urn=t2.urn)
```

Comment: I know the Query Optimizer is smart enough to catch this, but rather than `WHERE t2.urn NOT IN (SELECT t1.urn FROM table1 t1)` use `WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table1 t1 WHERE t1.urn = t2.urn)`

Comment: yeah thats true as Exists is faster than IN.I missed that

Comment: it's `urn` instead of `rn` (I think =) but otherwise, yes that's indeed what I meant. +1'd you already so can't do it again =)

As for the reason to use it : like I said, the Query Optimizer will translate the `NOT IN ()` into a `WHERE NOT EXISTS` on the fly so you won't really win much, but it's much more readable (IMHO) and it also works when your PK has more than one field which is pretty much impossible to handle with the `NOT IN ()` construction. (** at least, not in a nice way =)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the syntax using merge, will work from sqlserver 2008:

```
merge into table1 t1 
using table2 t2 on t1.urn = t2.urn
when not matched then
insert (urn,date)values(t2.urn,t2.date)
when matched then
update
set t1.date = t2.date;
```